# How to link with specific name (version) of a shared library

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I searched this problem here and find some similar question but there solutions not work for me. Here is my problem:
My application is compiling with shared library of openldap-2.3. Openldap has /usr/lib/libldap-2.3.so.0 which is linked to /usr/lib/libldap-2.3.so.0.2.31. I passed `-lldap` option to gcc, which linked the libldap-2.3.so.0 file to my application.

But i want to link with specific name like libldap.so. **Please correct me**, in future if i change the openldap version to 2.4 in development system, it will then link to the libldap-2.4.so.XXX version.

So How can I link my application to specific name, so that it will always look for same name like libldap.so.

**NOTE:** I created a softlink of /usr/lib/libldap-2.3.so.0 as /usr/lib/libldap.so and then pass the library name `/usr/lib/libldap.so` to compiler without `-l` then application compiled successfully without any linking error but still showing same libldap-2.3.so.0 in dependency.

Comment: in the future if you change the library you could just change the link to point to the new one, wouldn't that solve the problem ?

Comment: just a guess - there so no possibilty to link against some general library. It always need to be linked with particular version of the library. If you change system, you need to re-build your app. Another possibility is not to link against shared library but to make "static" app

Comment: @mux I am using "-l" option in gcc so it will link my app to new library like libldap-2.4.so.0 but it will ask for the same name in the system where I run my application. I want that fix.

Comment: @xhudik Adding static library can remove the dependency from openldap package library but it will make my app bigger :-(. which I can't afford. But thanks for your suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The [shared library mechanism](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) (the link is oldish, but still relevant) in Unix works by linking the executable at build time against e.g. liba.so, which is a symbolic link to liba.so.1, which in turn is a link to liba.so.1.2. The executable then records liba.so.1 to load when starting up. If you update liba.so, it could be to liba.so.1.5 (no ABI change, first digit doesn't change), the links look like liba.so --> liba.so.1 --> liba.so.1.5, and your executable now uses 1.5 transparently. If the version goes to liba.so.2.0 (API change!), the system makes liba.so --> liba.so.2 --> liba.so.2.0. Your old executable still uses 1.5, any newly built program will now reference 2. All this works as long as 1.x stays around, obviously. Presumably your distribution offers library packages that can be installed in paralell, or some `compat-liba-1` package for the benefit of old executables.